# Datatables (jquery) style page numbers error

Tags: css, datatables

I'm using datatables with the theme UI darkness. The table looks great except the page numbers in bottom right.

It looks like this:

[image]

I have styles and images on correct paths. Any ideas?

SOLVED: I added jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css and then it worked.

Comment: Consider to add relative css and html, otherwise people have to guess your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of your css files overwrite theme styles with his own and you got this. Look into firebug to understand this.

Comment: Tried removing the main.css from header. Still no luck. Is there some simple css i can add to the div?